# puppeteer get instagram profile checkbox value - HTML does not change

Tags: checkbox, instagram, puppeteer

Learning puppeteer... thought Instagram would be a good starting point.

Trying to see if my account in Instagram is configured to be a "Private Account" under [Privacy and Security](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/privacy_and_security/). My confusion is that the HTML for checked and unchecked is just about the same:

Checked:

[image]

```
<div class="qlmO5"><div class="bGWmh" id="accountPrivacy"><label class="U17kh PLphk" for="f2ef028392b78b8"><input class="tlZCJ" id="f2ef028392b78b8" type="checkbox" value="" checked=""><div class="mwD2G"></div>Private Account</label></div></div>
```

Unchecked:

[image]

```
<div class="qlmO5"><div class="bGWmh" id="accountPrivacy"><label class="U17kh PLphk" for="f111b1f63405c24"><input class="tlZCJ" id="f111b1f63405c24" type="checkbox" value="" checked=""><div class="mwD2G"></div>Private Account</label></div></div>
```

I thought it might be the `<input>`'s `id` value but that does not change based on the value of the checkbox. I also tried diffing the entire html of checked vs unchecked and they were identical.

In this case, am I supposed to take a screenshot and see if I can match an image of "☑ Private Account"? I feel that this may be possible, but not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is indeed identical in both cases, but the DOM tree isn't. When private account "checkbox" is checked, the `.mwD2G` div gets a `:before` element which does the styling, so you can check for it in `page.evaluate`:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".mwD2G"), ":before").getPropertyValue("content")
```

So if the box is checked, the result of the query is `" "`, if unchecked, `none`.

```
const privateProfile = await page.evaluate(() =>
    window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".mwD2G"), ":before")
    .getPropertyValue("content") === "none" ? false : true)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you!
```const account_privacy = await page.evaluate(() => window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".mwD2G"), ":before").getPropertyValue("content") === "none" ? false : true)
console.log('Account Privacy checkbox status:', account_privacy)```

Comment: Also was able to use the same strategy to get remaining checkboxes:
```const show_activity_status = await page.evaluate(() => window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelectorAll(".mwD2G")[1], ":before").getPropertyValue("content") === "none" ? false : true) console.log('Account Privacy checkbox status:', account_privacy)```

Comment: How did you find this out?

Comment: What exactly do you mean about how I found out?

Comment: I looked in the DOM tree and didn't see :before. How did you find the pseudo-element?

Comment: I researched the DOM in Chrone's DevTools. It is not shown by default, you would need to press the triangle on the parent element to see it.